# How to get postgres query created by Loopback 4 before it hits database?

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

I want to sort based on the nested property of Loopback 4. I can't find any direct way in Loopback 4 for this.

```
http://localhost:3000/pictures?filter={"where":{"and":[{"isParent":1}]},"include":[{"relation":"comment"},{"relation":"profile"}],"offset":0,"order":["profile.fullName ASC"],"limit":5}
```

This gives an error coz profile.fullName is a nested property from relation.

So to find a solution for this, I was thinking what if I can get the Postgres query created by Loopback 4 and manipulate the query, and then hit the database. Can this be done?

Any help, highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on the debugging flag for database connection

```
DEBUG=loopback:connector:* npm run start
```